# Topics consumed by logstash show zero lag

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack

I have trouble with fetching data from Kafka to Logstash.
Actually I can vizualise my logs correctly in Kibana after using logstash to get them there but when I return back to my Kafka console I realize that my topics are consumed.

LAG is 0 as you can see as follow.

```
    TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
F1              0          0               0               0               -               -               -
topic4log       1          47              47              0               -               -               -
topic4log       0          45              45              0               -               -               -
topic1          0          1               1               0               -               -               -
topic1          1          3               3               0               -               -               -
```

I followed the [Kafka input plugin guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html) and tried to change many configurations options but still I have the same issue.

My goal is only the vizualisation of my kafka topics without consuming any of the existing producers.

FYI, here is my logstash configuration file.

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => ["topic4log", "topic1"]
    auto_offset_reset => "latest"
    consumer_threads => 1
    enable_auto_commit => "true"
    decorate_events => true
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "events-%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}-%{[@metadata][kafka][partition]}-%{[@metadata][kafka][consumer_group]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) please use code blocks, not images 2) You're starting the consumer at the latest offset... Are you actively putting data in those topics? And what do you mean by "without consuming any existing producers"?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem, You can't visualize Kafka Logs without consuming them, if you are not pushing more data to kafka, your lag for the logstash consumer group will always be 0.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I'm actively putting data on those topics.
I mean if I get my kafka log on logstash the lag value changed which means that logstash is consuming from my toipcs.

Comment: If logstash was working correctly, then `CONSUMER-ID` and `CLIENT-ID` shouldn't be just dashes, but if you see data in Kibana, what exactly is the issue?